# Pandas change data structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this (its just an example):

```
date(YYYY-mm-dd)   money   money_diff        acc
2019-02-01          110      diff_1      236234623-1
2019-03-01          244      diff_2      236234623-1
2019-04-01          402      diff_3      236234623-1
2019-02-01          429      diff_4      876567856-k
2019-03-01          424      diff_5      876567856-k
2019-04-01          125      diff_6      876567856-k
2019-08-01          346      diff_7      876567856-k
    ...             ...       ...
2020-01-01          348      diff_20     456745675-5
2020-02-01          745      diff_21     456745675-5
2020-03-01          457      diff_22     456745675-5
2020-04-01          567      diff_23     023603460-0
2020-05-01          774      diff_24     023603460-0
   ...              ...       ...            ...
2023-01-01          245      diff_43     634034060-3
2023-02-01          458      diff_44     634034060-3
2023-03-01          457      diff_45     634034060-3
```

What I want is for the `acc` column to be the first column (with unique str values), the values ​​of the `date` column to be my other headers, and the values ​​inside to be those of `money_diff` column. What I want is to have a tabular structure like this (I can `drop` `money` column, I will not use it):

```
        acc                 2019-02-01    2019-03-01     2019-04-01   ...   2023-03-01
     236234623-1              diff_1        diff_2         diff_3     ...    diff_X1
     876567856-k              diff_4        diff_5         diff_6     ...    diff_X2
     456745675-5              diff_X3       diff_X4        diff_X5    ...    diff_X6
     023603460-0              diff_X6       diff_X7        diff_X8    ...    diff_X9
     634034060-3              diff_X10      diff_X11       diff_X12   ...    diff_45
```

I know that the requirement for this is that `acc` column have the same dates, and yes, they do.

I tried to use `pd.melt` function but I didn't have my results:

```
pd.melt(df, id_values='acc', var_values='money_diff','date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pivot` and `reset_index`

```
df.pivot(index='acc', columns='date(YYYY-mm-dd)', values='money_diff').reset_index()
```